# Java - Check if user is domain admin of google apps domain

Tags: java, google-api, google-apps, gdata-api, google-api-java-client

I want to know if he given user is admin of google apps domain or not. getting a list of domain admins will also do.

`userService.isUserAdmin()` gives user admin of google app engine which I don't want.I want to check if user is admin of google Apps domain.

I found that we can use read only access to provisioning api for this,but I could not get any detailed tutorial or code.I also need the authentication for read only access using oAuth 2 only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read-only Provisioning API access is only available to [Google Apps Marketplace applications](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/marketplace/manifest#supported_scopes) using two-legged OAuth 1.0. If you're not developing a Marketplace App, you'll need to get the full read-write users scope.

A java example is available at:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/#retrieving_user_accounts